# Why background image is not showing up?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

My html code is shown below:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="center">
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="lr">
    <p> paragraph </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and content-wrapper section in .css is as follows:

```
.content-wrapper{ 
    background-image: url(/picture.jpg);  
    background-position: center center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I am not able to get the background image behind my texts. 
I don't want to set background image through the direct body tag. 
I am stuck here. 
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Is the `/picture.jpg` correct path to the image? What does the browser console say?

Comment: My code is working fine if I am using **body tag** in css instead of .content-wrapper but when I am using **.content-wrapper** it is not showing up the image infact I have added **bgcolor** also that so that if the picture location is not correct then a solid color would show up but none of them are working. 
It is not including .content-wrapper. Need help.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you expect?
If yes, your code seems okay. Be sure your image is referenced well.

```css
.content-wrapper{ 
    background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/sayob/image/upload/v1526907328/483257_vwhhfw.jpg");  
    background-position: center center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="center">
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="lr">
    <p> paragraph </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: picture location is fine. Even still it is not showing up. Need help.

Comment: if you look at the network tab in your dev tools, is it getting loaded?

Comment: @AkanshaGautam Also make sure your image url is encoded in a string as `url("picture.jpg");`

Comment: @OluwasayoBabalola Here is the link to my code at JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Akansha/vtL28yrp/

Comment: @DomenikReitzner yes it is loading there. 
here is the link to my code at JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Akansha/vtL28yrp/

Comment: @AkanshaGautam: as Joseph pointed out the height is missing. I would also be careful about the mixed content warning I in the console. Just load over https :)

Answer (score 1):

@Akansha, your code is fine with the exception that you failed to give your container a height. In other words, your background is there, you just can't see it.

By default, block elements have a default width of 100%, but there is no default height. Background images do not effect the height of the element either. So, a height must be added.

```css
.content-wrapper{ 
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/sayob/image/upload/v1526907328/483257_vwhhfw.jpg");  
    background-position: center center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="center">
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="lr">
    <p> paragraph </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see this code in effect here: https://jsfiddle.net/j_pinder/nkLf03ao/2/

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give height of the image also. `height:100vh` `vh: hundredths of the viewport height`. You can define height in `px` or `percentage` also.

```css
.content-wrapper{ 
    background-image: url("https://preview.ibb.co/e5OShF/cropped_800_480_111290.jpg ");  
    background-position: center center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="center">
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="lr">
    <p> paragraph </p>
  </div>
</div>
```